# What kind of diode for a solenoid?

Tags: diodes, protection, solenoid, circuit-protection

I have a solenoid of 5V, 1.2A.

Can I use the diode 1N914 for protection?
http://www.mouser.com/Search/m_ProductDetail.aspx?Fairchild-Semiconductor%2F1N914%2F&qs=NSEUUqpg2uCfNuQFcxVZsA%3D%3D

Comment: Hard to make a decision if you don't tell us what you're trying to achieve. However, typically, for solenoid valves, if you're planning on using a microcontroller to program the solenoid valve to turn off and on using a transistor, you typically want a good flyback diode. For my senior project in college, I used a 1N4001 flyback diode.

Comment: 5 V, 1.2 A is not enough to give you an answer. What's the coil voltage and inductance? What do you want to protect, inductive kickback from the coil or inductive kickback from your long cable in your main current path?

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer is that you can, maybe, if you're feeling lucky, and you have no real problem with what happens if the diode fails. This is one of those really marginal ideas and is not a good one.

Now, for the longer answer. I'm assuming that you are using the diode as a flyback diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ9j1c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where the solenoid is switched on an off by some sort of switch, shown here as a transistor.

When the switch opens, the inductance of the solenoid coil will cause the switch voltage to rise until the diode conducts, and the voltage will stay high until the current has dissipated.

When the switch is on, the diode is reverse-biased, so it must be rated for the solenoid voltage, in this case 5 volts.

When the diode conducts after the switch turns off, its peak current is the solenoid current, or 1.2 amps in this case. However, it doesn't need to conduct this current indefinitely, while the normal current rating for a diode is based on DC operation.

How does this affect a 1N914? Look at [a typical data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85622/1n914.pdf). The forward continuous current is 300 mA, which is clearly not enough. But the non-repetitive pulse current is 1 A for a 1-second pulse, and 4 amps for a 1 usec pulse. So, how long will the pulse last? Without knowing the inductance of the coil (which is almost certainly the dominant inductance, grossly exceeding the wiring inductance) there is no way to know, so it's best not to take chances - particularly since diodes are cheap.

To be conservative and avoid heartburn, the simplest route would be to use a 1.2 amp diode, although 1.2 amps is an unusual number. Could you use a 1 amp diode? Almost certainly. As was suggested in comment, a 1N4001 can be considered. Looking at [the data sheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28002.pdf) you'll see that the average current rating is 1 amp. This is a bit low, but the pulse rating is 30 amps.

So, I would recommend (very strongly) against a 1N914, but I can't guarantee that it would fail. Something like a 1N4001 would be much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

What you are worried about is known as a transient voltage spike. These are very hard to calculate. For our stuff here (24V/1A) we use RL207-TP diodes.  These have a reverse breakdown voltage of 1000V (which is normally good enough for the spikes) and rated for 2A of current.  We use these all day on our PLCs and have yet to have issues. I've linked the Digikey link of this diode below.

[Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/micro-commercial-co/RL207-TP/RL207-TPCT-ND/950504)

Comment: Thank you all! I am using 1 1N4004 diode as per your sugeestions.